# pointers & 'Illegal instruction (core dumped)' in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I want to write a syntactical analyzer, but when I ran the code, it gave me this:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Now, I ran the debugger, and it tells me that at the first iteration (so it cant be contextual), the error happens here:

```
static int list(int poz, int *size) {
...
if(*size==poz)
...
```

this function is called like this:

```
list(-1,&size);
```

here is the entire code that does things:

```
static int nexttoken() {
  if(pointer==filesize)
    return -1;
  return cchar=file[++pointer];///file is an array where i keep the contents of the file (without spaces)
  
}
static void getint(int *atr) {
  *atr=0;
  while(isdigit(nexttoken()))
    *atr=(*atr)*10+cchar-'0';
  return;
}

///...

static int atom() {
  int integer,size,currentpoz;
  getint(&integer);
  while(cchar=='(') {
    currentpoz=pointer;
    list(-1,&size);
    integer%=size;
    pointer=currentpoz;
    integer=list(integer,&size);
    nexttoken();
  }
  return integer;
}
static int list(int poz,int *size) {
  *size=0;
  int retval=0;
  while(nexttoken()!=')') {
    if(*size==poz)
      retval=atom();
    else
      atom();
    *size++;
  }
  return retval;
}
```

I ran the same code on another compiler, it told me it was segfault (SIGSIEV).
I do not know what could be causing the problem, or how does a pointer even gives me any of this.

Thanks in advance,

Mihai

Comment: regarding: `return cchar=file[++pointer]`   This will return the status of the assignment, NOT the contents of `cchar`

Comment: regarding: `currentpoz=pointer;`  What is `pointer`?  And why assign a pointer to an integer?

Comment: @user3629249 , 'pointer' is a variable that tells me where i am right now in file. because of the nature of the grammari am implementing, i would need to know where to find the value (i.e i first call list to find the 'size' of the upcoming list, then i call that function once again to find the value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
*size++;
```

That's your likely culprit - you're not updating the value `size` points to, you're changing `size` to point to a different object.  Postfix `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so that expression is parsed as `*(size++)`.

Rewrite that as

```
(*size)++;
```

and see if that doesn't make the issue go away.

Answer (score 1):

For starters this function looks suspiciously

```
static int nexttoken() {
  if(pointer==filesize)
    return -1;
  return cchar=file[++pointer];///file is an array where i keep the contents of the file (without spaces)
  
}
```

The expression `++pointer` can be equal to `filesize`. This can invoke undefined behavior.

Should it be `cchar=file[pointer++]`?

And correspondingly the function `list` should be called like

```
list( 0, &size);
```

instead of

```
list(-1,&size);
```

Within the function `list` this expression

```
*size++;
```

is equivalent to

```
*( size++ );
```

That is the object pointed to by the pointer `size` is not being changed.

Instead you have to write

```
++*size;
```

Also it is a bad idea when functions depend on global variables.